# Compiling .xsl files into .class files

Tags: java, performance, xslt, compilation

I'm currently working on a Java web project (Spring) which involves heavy use of xsl transformations. The stylesheets seldom change, so they are currently cached. I was thinking of improving performance by compiling the xsl-s into class files so they wouldn't have to be interpreted on each request.

I'm new to Java, so I don't really know the ecosystem that well. What's the best way of doing this (libraries, methods etc.)?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need a Template and a stylesheet cache:

http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html?page=9

Do be careful about thread safety, because Transformers aren't thread safe.  Best to do your transformations in a ThreadLocal for isolation.

Answer (score 4):

You might not have to compile to `.class` to achieve your goal, you can compile the xsl once per run and re-use the compiled instance for all transformations.

To do so you create a `Templates` object, like:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
factory.setErrorListener(new ErrorListener( ... ));
xslTemplate = factory.newTemplates(new StreamSource( ... ));
```

and use the template to get a transformer to do the work:

```
Transformer transformer = xslTemplate.newTransformer();
```

Depending on the XSL library you use your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Gregor/XSLT compiler